# "next" and "for" functions wont work correctly

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Hinnan_korotus_välilehti_makro()
    Dim tulostusrivi As Integer
    Dim lukurivi As Integer
    Dim lukurivi_tausta As Integer
    Dim uusihinta As Double

    Sheets("Nimikkeitä").Select

    For lukurivi = 75 To 400
        If Range("F" & lukurivi) = "Hawle" Then
            nimike = Range("A" & lukurivi)
            Sheets("Taul1").Select

            For tulostusrivi = 2 To 400
                If Range("A" & tulostusrivi) = nimike Then
                    uusihinta = Range("F" & tulostusrivi)
                    Sheets("Nimikkeitä").Select
                    Range("E" & lukurivi) = uusihinta
                End If
            Next tulostusrivi
        End If
    Next lukurivi
End Sub
```

Hi I have a problem with "for" and "next" functions.. Last few lines where macro has placed "uusihinta" to Range "E" & lukurivi. I Want to go back after "End if" to top "lukurivi" and next line which is 76. But it keeps looping "tulostusrivi" and never goes to "Next lukurivi".
Thank you!

Comment: After `Range("E" & lukurivi) = uusihinta`  you need to add `Exit For` on the next line

Comment: Yup, sounds like a job for "Exit For".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Double Loop

The short answer was already given in the comments by [IAmNerd2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10938799/iamnerd2000) and [Eleshar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6736247/eleshar): You are missing the `Exit For` line. Below is an optimized, over commented version of your code which you might find instructive.

### Tips

- It is customary not to use underscores "**_**" in macro titles, but
  to use capital letters: `HinnanKorotusVälilehti`, `HinKorVäl` or
  `HKV` instead of Hinnan_korotus_välilehti. And shorter titles are
  preferred (`Makro` is really not necessary in the title).
- Always use `Option Explicit` for the compiler to find variables that
  are not declared (`nimike`).
- Start variables with lower case letters and introduce uppercase
  letters to divide words e.g. `lukuRivi` or `tulostusRivi`.
- [Long vs
  Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)
- Remove unused variables (`lukurivi_tausta`).
- Do not add unnecessary variables e.g. NOT `A = B: C = A` but `C = B`
  (`uusihinta`).
- Do not use `Select` or `Activate` if not necessary, because they slow
  down your code.
- Add variable descriptions or titles for you (after a while) and others
  to better understand the code.
- Use object variables (`ws`) to make use of Intellisense.
- Use the `With` statement to divide codes of different objects (not quite a demonstration here).
- When data (rows) will be added the hard coded last row (`400`) will
  always have to be changed. Therefore it is better to calculate it
  every time using the `End` property or the `Find` method.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub HinnanKorotusVälilehti()

    Dim ws As Worksheet       ' Worksheet Variable for worksheet "Taul1"
    Dim lukuRivi As Long      ' Worksheet "Nimikkeitä" Row Counter
    Dim tulostusRivi As Long  ' Worksheet "Taul1" Row Counter
    Dim nimike As String      ' Product Title

    ' Create a reference to worksheet "Taul1" (Everything starting with
    ' "ws." is referring to workhsheet "Taul1").
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Taul1")

    ' In Worksheet "Nimikkeitä" (Everything starting with a "." is referring
    ' to worksheet "Nimikkeitä".)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nimikkeitä")
        ' Loop through rows of worksheet "Nimikkeitä".
        For lukuRivi = 75 To 400
            ' Check if the cell at the intersection of the current row
            ' and column "F" contains "Hawle".
            If .Range("F" & lukuRivi) = "Hawle" Then ' IS "Hawle"
                ' Assign the value of the cell at the intersection of the
                ' current row and column "A" to variable "nimike".
                nimike = .Range("A" & lukuRivi)
                ' (In Worksheet Taul1) Loop through rows of Worksheet Taul1.
                For tulostusRivi = 2 To 400
                    ' Check if the cell at the intersection of the current row
                    ' and column "A" contains (the value of) "nimike".
                    If ws.Range("A" & tulostusRivi) = nimike Then ' IS "nimike".
                        ' Write the value of the cell at the intersection of
                        ' the current row (tulostusRivi) and the "F" column
                        ' in worksheet "Taul1" to the cell at the intersection
                        ' of the current row (lukuRivi) and the "E" column in
                        ' worksheet "Nimikkeitä".
                        .Range("E" & lukuRivi) = ws.Range("F" & tulostusRivi)
                        ' Since the value has been found, stop searching and
                        ' go to next row in worksheet "Nimikkeitä".
                        Exit For
                      'Else ' NOT "nimike".
                    End If
                Next ' Next row in worksheet "Taul1" (tulostusRivi).
              'Else  ' NOT "Hawle".
            End If
        Next ' Next row in worksheet "Nimikkeitä" (lukuRivi).
    End With

End Sub
```